# Displaying contents of XML file alphabetically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to get the contents of an .XML file and then display the list in alphabetical order.

Here's the setup for the XML document:

```
   <markers>
      <marker school="University of One" names="Bob One, Bob Two, Bob Three" lat="32.235260" lng="-130.980506" />
      <marker school="University of One" names="Bob One, Bob Two, Bob Three" lat="32.235260" lng="-130.980506" />
   </markers>
```

I then fetch the contents of that file (seniors.xml) with this jQuery:

```
  downloadUrl("seniors.xml", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      // obtain the attribues of each marker
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var names = markers[i].getAttribute("names");
      var school = markers[i].getAttribute("school");
      var html="<b class="+'school-name'+">"+school+"</b><br><p class="+'student-names'+">"+names+"</p><br>";
      // create the marker
      var marker = createMarker(point,school+" "+names,html);
    }

    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);

    // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
  });
}
```

I define in another function what side_bar_html will do (this stores the list and puts the information into the sidebar).

```
side_bar_html += '<div id="'+linkid+'" class="'+'sidebar-link-box'+'"><div class="'+'padded'+'"><a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')" class="sidebar-link">' + html + '<\/a><\/div><\/div>';
```

My HTML looks like the following. Note that the action of the form is not set because I have a jQuery keyup event to queue the search.

```
        <form id="live-search" action="">
           <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" size="50" placeholder="Search for student/school" tabindex="1"/>
           <span id="filter-count"></span>
        </form>

        <!-- display results -->
       <div id="side_bar"></div> 

       </div>
```

Everything works well; the results display, but I'm not sure how to make them appear in alphabetical order. Should I run an alphabetical function before/after I put the list into side_bar_html?

Comment: Map the markers into a javascript array, then sort the array before using it to build the HTML.

Comment: @Nick on which attribute you want to sort

Comment: @ArunPJohny I would like to sort the list by school. I think your will work, but since the rest of the code to create the map element is in JavaScript (not jQuery) I'm not able to test it. Is there a quick way to convert your code into JavaScript? Or should it work if I load it later in the page with a separate <script> tag? Will it register JavaScript functions in jQuery?

Comment: jquery is javasript, I used jquery since the question is having jquery tag. are you using jquery in your page

Comment: For some reason the code doesn't seem to have an effect on the pre-existing data. Essentially the sorting doesn't take effect. I'm using my previous code with yours afterwards, the thought being that my code will output the content into the sidebar and then yours would organize it alphabetically. This might be the problem. If I want to switch over to just yours, how should I get the other variables (lat, lng, point)? I don't need to organize them, I just want to fetch them so that I can use them to create the Google Maps marker point.

Answer (score 0):

Set scroll property to true inside adjust element as below

```
this.elements.tooltip.qtip(
      {
         content: 'I tooltip!', 
         position: {
            corner: {
               tooltip: 'topMiddle',
               target: 'bottomMiddle'
            },
            adjust: {
               resize: true,
               scroll: true
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function(){

  $.get('seniors.xml', function(xmlDoc){
    var $doc = $(xmlDoc);

    var array = $doc.find('marker').get();
    array.sort(function(obj1, obj2){
      var $obj1 = $(obj1), $obj2 = $(obj2)

      var s1 = $obj1.attr('school'), s2 = $obj2.attr('school');
      if(s1 == s2){
        var n1 = $obj1.attr('names'), n2 = $obj2.attr('names');
        return n1 < n2 ? -1 : 1
      } else {
        return s1 < s2 ? -1 : 1
      }
    });

    $(array).each(function(index, item){
      var $item = $(item);
      $('<li>' + $item.attr('school') + '--' + $item.attr('names') + '</li>').appendTo('#ct')
    });

  }, 'xml');

});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Pd6kWfGAg2yVNGEwJVy?p=preview)

Comment: Providing the sort direction is the same for both criteria, I think the 2-criterion sort can be simplified (though maybe not made more efficient) by comparing a concatenation of the two strings `school + name`.